# How ask mysql for many queries at once, similar to for loop

Tags: mysql

I need change data in DB. The structure of command is easy, but I need to repeat it with different parameters 100 times. Is there any chance how to do it not manually?

```
UPDATE OBSERVATION SET  VALUE_METADATA= 'ERG_KP' WHERE PARAMETER_STABLE_ID = 'CCP_017' AND VALUE_METADATA='KP'
```

Only the value in single quotes should be changed. Thanks

Comment: From where you get this three parameter from some other tables or CSV or?

Comment: There's not enough information to supply an answer. It would be quicker if you just did it.